# Background image not sizing correctly with browser zoom

Tags: css, image, browser, responsive-design, zooming

I am having problems with a site's header displaying correctly when a person zooms in with the browser. The banner will cut off on the right side and show the body background image. The address to the site is: http://www.bemidjisportsonline.com, Any ideas on a way to fix this? Thanks. I will post my CSS for the body, header, and banner elements below. A screenshot of what I am talking about can be found here: http://prntscr.com/19e59r.

```
body{
    font: 100%/1.25 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /*background: url(/_images/background-repeated.png) top center repeat-x;*/
    background: url(/_images/background_jersey_green.jpg) #010101 top center repeat-x;
}

header, nav, section, article, aside, footer {display:block;}

header{
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    background: url(/_images/header_trees.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 7em;
}

#banner{
    z-index:100002;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:75em;
    height:7em;
}
```

Comment: It seems that when the browser is zoomed in to a certain point, it will look like it is scaling properly, but when the bottom slider bar is moved to the right. You can see that the banner and nav backgrounds are getting cut off on the right side.

Comment: I made somewhat of a fix by giving the body element a min-width of 1200px;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `background-size`. Like this:

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: url(/_images/header_trees.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 7em;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I feel like a dummy. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the #banner width to 100%.

```
#banner {
z-index: 100002;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 7em;
```

}

Comment: This sort of worked. It will scale with the width of the browser window, but the height of the image then becomes off.